# attribute or property?

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

[image: 1st image of the book's text]

[image: 2nd Image of the book's text]

In the first paragraph in first image, there is an attribute currentTip.

In the second image, in second heading- the code is pageContent.getCurrentTip() and in third heading the code is 
"jsp:getPropery name='pageContent' property ='currentTip'/>"

My question is that there is no description of the variable pageContent and currentTip is accessed by the code that is used to get the property of attributes set in some scope. Because in previous examples of the book, the attributes are java bean objects  and their properties are got by the getter methods. So here, it is apparent that currentTip is not an attribute but it is a property of the attribute pageContent. Is currentTip an attribute as taught by the book or it is property of attribute pageContent?

Comment: As already answered in your deleted [very first question on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668404/jsp-and-servlets-headfirst-book), this is a mistake of the book's author. However you argued that the book is correct. What do you want us to tell you?

Comment: SIR, the answer you gave was that it is on the errata of the publishing house's website. And answer was that pageContent is a wrapper object but whether currentTip is an attribute or property, it was given nowhere? Website says that it is corrected in new books, but it is not. Neither in print nor in pdfs on internet, there is any correction. And kindly understand, it was very difficult for me to get the book from internet and post its pages. I would not bother you respected people without any reason. And perhaps, I never argued with u. So I ask whether currentTip is attribute or property?

Comment: If it's been set as an attribute by `someScope.setAttribute()`, then it's an attribute. If it's been  set as a property by `someBean.setPropertyName()`, then it's a property. Simple as that.

Comment: SIR, had there been code signifying how the variable has been set, there would have been no confusion. The two pages above give no information "someScope.setAttribute()" or "someBean.setPropertyName()" 
The book says on page 383(on pages above) that currentTip is a request scoped attribute but on the page 384 as posted with the question, pageContent.getCurrentTip() and "jsp:getPropery name='pageContent' property ='currentTip'/>" these two statements are being used to get currentTip. This kind of code has been used to get the value of property of an attribute. Thank You SIR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording in the first paragraph is incorrect. The request-scope attribute is `pageContent`. Since the JSP code uses `${pageContent.currentTip}`, this means that `currentTip` is a property of the bean stored in the attribute `pageContent`. Your understanding is thus correct, and the first paragraph of the book is wrong.